# Vim Code Reading - Closing/Minimizing Brackets

Tags: perl, vim

I have to read a few giant Perl scripts, and I would like to know how do you guys add the "minimizing" brackets functionality in Vim as GUI text editors do. I'm having a tough time understanding the code because of this, If I could just minimize those giant if, functions, etc... my mind would be very grateful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By *minimizing*, I suppose you are referring to code "folding"

```
:help fold
```

<kbd>z</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>  closes all folds recursively under the cursor, <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> closes a single fold.  <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> opens a single fold under the cursor, while <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> recursively opens all folds.

See also

```
:help :foldmethod
```

For Perl, you will want `:set foldmethod=syntax`.

Comment: "folding" i bet that's the word, had a tough time figuring it out.